# Facebook Invite Friends to app - Dialogs requests

Tags: facebook, api, invite

I use this code for inviting facebook friends to app : http://pastebin.com/A4LkB8sF

```
FB.ui({ method: ‘apprequests’, message: ‘Facebook Promotion App’ });
```

Its working fine but if they click the Link in the FB notification bar they dont get linked directly to my page and app. Instead they are at a “step between”. The app is visible in an iframe with less than 810px and no like button.

This are the link parameters:

***/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=12345621890&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request***

Where is the problem? Why is FB not linking the user to the app in page directly?

I guess the solution is somewhere in the App settings maybe… but i dont know.

Please help me, is important ?

Answer (score 0):

Specify `redirect_uri` also in the parameters list.

Comment: Are you sure app requests support redirect_uri?

Comment: You must search that in the docs from your own, btw here it is : [Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: I read it. But nowhere in the FB.ui method of sending requests is mentioned. It is shown only for direct link requests and the question was about FB.ui